# how to rewrite code into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a code like this:

```
var data =[
  [{qText:"A"},{qText:"type1"},{qText: 5}],
  [{qText:"A"},{qText:"type2"},{qText: 3}],
  [{qText:"A"},{qText:"type3"},{qText: 5}],
  .......

 ]
```

How can i rewrite it so it would be this way ?

```
var data = [
  { team: "A", type1: "5", type2: "3", type3: "5" },
  { team: "B", type1: "0", type2: "3", type3: "3" },
  { team: "C", type1: "8", type2: "2", type3: "4" },
];
```

Comment: did you try anthing so far?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how your input gets turned into your output ...where does "B" and "C" come from? And all those other values that appear in your out but not in your input?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - or at the very least show some attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the array with the objects and find same team in the result set or add a new object. Then assign the stringed value to the given key.

```js
var data = [[{ qText: "A" }, { qText: "type1" }, { qText: 5 }], [{ qText: "A" }, { qText: "type2" }, { qText: 3 }], [{ qText: "A" }, { qText: "type3" }, { qText: 5 }], [{ qText: "B" }, { qText: "type1" }, { qText: 0 }], [{ qText: "B" }, { qText: "type2" }, { qText: 3 }], [{ qText: "B" }, { qText: "type3" }, { qText: 3 }], [{ qText: "C" }, { qText: "type1" }, { qText: 8 }], [{ qText: "C" }, { qText: "type2" }, { qText: 2 }], [{ qText: "C" }, { qText: "type3" }, { qText: 4 }]],
    result = data.reduce((r, [{ qText: team }, { qText: key }, { qText: value }]) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => o.team === team);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { team });
        temp[key] = value.toString();
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```